# How to execute two functions using toggle in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used toggle() function for executing two functions.
When I click the image with class="favourite", on first click, the first function must be executed and I should get the alert('test1') and for second click, the second function must be executed and I should get the alert('test2') and  the execution must stop there.

My problem is that, When the image is clicked for the second time, I am getting alert('test2') followed by alert('test1'), only second function should be executed for second click i.e. I should get only alert('test2') on second click. How to stop the execution of the first function on second click?

This is my jquery code in index.phtml file:

```
jqry("#wrap").delegate('img.favourite','click',function(){ 
    var id = jqry(this).attr('pid');
    jqry('#'+id).toggle(function(){
            alert('test1');     
        },
        function(){
            alert('test2');
        }
    );
});
```

This is my code in JS file

```
    <img class="favourite"  src="images/fav.png" alt="favourite" pid ='project_id'>
```

The output I am getting on first click is
`test1`

The output I am getting on second click is
`test2`
`test1`

On second click I should get the output alert `test2` and stop the execution, but it is further executing the previous function and giving both the alerts i.e `test2` followed by `test1`. How can I solve this?

Comment: Indenting your code would make it a lot more readable.

Comment: A couple of things I don't understand. You are calling `#+id` even though you don't have an id on your image. Also, if you toggle the image, how are you supposed to click it the second time? If it's hidden?

Comment: @Niklas - I think they're calling `.toggle()` on some other object.  But, it is certainly not clear what they're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form of `.toggle()` that you are using was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9.  In addition, it binds a click handler each time it is called so you really don't want to be calling it multiple times which is probably why you see two alerts because each time you bind it, you get one more callback on a click.  First one, then two, then three, etc...

I'd suggest you find a different way of alternating functions on each click.  Perhaps just set a flag on the item with `.data()` and alternate based on the flag.

It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do with the `.toggle()` function on the id element, but this will get you alternating function calls and you can then implement whatever you want in each function:

```
jqry("#wrap").delegate('img.favourite', 'click', function() { 
    var toggle = $(this).data("toggleFlag") || false;
    var id = jqry(this).attr('pid');
    if (toggle) {
         // do whatever you want with id here
         alert("test1");
    } else {
         // do whatever you want with id here
         alert("test2");
    }
    // reverse the toggle flag
    $(this).data("toggleFlag", !toggle);
});
```

Comment: @Rajitha - since you're new here on StackOverflow, you should know that when someone answers your question (or best answer of many), you can check the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  This indicates to others which answer you selected and it earns both you and the answerer some reputation points (which can earn you privileges on the site over time).

Comment: thank you, it works!! but when I load page the function runs only after two clicks and then it works fine but if refresh page I need to click twice again. How to solve this?

Comment: Ya I'm about to and now I checked the green check mark

Comment: @Rajitha - I'd have to see more of the page and your actual code to know why it needs extra clicks.

Comment: All the code is what I pasted in my query. If this works fine I need to implement it by placing the actual code near the alert. For now I want to know why I need to click 2 times for getting the first alert and what should I do to run on first click.

Comment: @Rajitha - If you want the first alert to happen on the first click, then change `if (toggle) {` to `if (!toggle) {`.